# How to set extra link argument in Python module setup?

Tags: python, module, installation

I am using setup tools to build a Python module and I need to add extra links. 
Parameter extra_link_args is not working.

Comment: More info, please

Comment: Hi. Thanks. It is solved. The problem was that extra_link_args is not a parameter to setup, but a parameter to Extension.

Comment: Then please share it with us. We would reward you with reputation points for improving our knowledge base.

Comment: Yes, I will. Rigth now.

Answer (score 2):

As I said, extra_link_args is not an argument to setup. It would be like this:

```
extra_link_args = []

if platform.system() == 'Darwin':
    extra_link_args.append('-Wl,-rpath,' + lib_path)

setup(
    name='Mymodule',
    #extra_link_args = extra_link_args this is wrong
     ext_modules = [Extension("_mymodule", ["mycfile.c"],
                         depends=[],
                         libraries = [':mylib.a'],
                         extra_link_args = extra_link_args, #this is right
                   )],
```