# ld: can't find -lGL error during installation

Tags: python, ubuntu, gcc, conda

I'm trying to install `mujoco-py` and get this after compilation:

```
  /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/compiler_compat/ld: cannot find -lGL
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mujoco-py
  Running setup.py clean for mujoco-py
  Failed to build mujoco-py
  ERROR: Could not build wheels for mujoco-py which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

I am using Ubuntu 18.04, Python 3.6.9.

---

Following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406369/qt-cant-find-lgl-error), I install the suggested library
, but turns out it was already installed.

```
(test_env) ubuntu@user:~$ sudo apt install libosmesa6-dev libgl1-mesa-glx libglfw3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libglfw3 is already the newest version (3.2.1-1).
libgl1-mesa-glx is already the newest version (19.0.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3).
libosmesa6-dev is already the newest version (19.0.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
```

I then try the second answer and run `locate libGL`. Strangely this doesn't return anything.

I also try creating the symbolic link directly:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
```

but:

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so': File exists
```

---

```
~$ ls -h /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu | grep "libGL"
libGL.la
libGL.so
libGL.so.1
libGL.so.1.7.0
libGLESv1_CM.so
libGLESv1_CM.so.1
libGLESv1_CM.so.1.0.0
libGLESv1_CM.so.1.2.0
libGLESv1_CM_nvidia.so.1
libGLESv1_CM_nvidia.so.418.87.01
libGLESv2.so
libGLESv2.so.2
libGLESv2.so.2.0.0
libGLESv2.so.2.1.0
libGLESv2_nvidia.so.2
libGLESv2_nvidia.so.418.87.01
libGLEW.so
libGLEW.so.2.0
libGLEW.so.2.0.0
libGLU.a
libGLU.so
libGLU.so.1
libGLU.so.1.3.1
libGLX.so
libGLX.so.0
libGLX_indirect.so.0
libGLX_mesa.so.0
libGLX_mesa.so.0.0.0
libGLX_nvidia.so.0
libGLX_nvidia.so.418.87.01
libGLdispatch.so
libGLdispatch.so.0
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your Anaconda is too old (or `setup.py` of the package is not right initially) and affected by this bug too:
https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi/issues/94

There in order to install the package the people recommend adding
`extra_link_args=['-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/']`

See also [How to set extra link argument in Python module setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51141613/how-to-set-extra-link-argument-in-python-module-setup)

Answer (score 0):

This helped me:

```
$ mamba install -c conda-forge mesa-libgl-devel-cos7-x86_64
```